# JavaFX TableView: howto move conditional cell styles to FXML/CSS?

Tags: css, javafx, tableview, fxml

I am trying to set style of text in cells in JavaFX Tableview. My model has  `StringProperty title, description;`  and `BooleanProperty warning;`

```
public class MyItem {
    @FXML
    private final StringProperty title =  new SimpleStringProperty();   
    @FXML
    private final StringProperty description =  new SimpleStringProperty();     
    @FXML
    private final BooleanProperty warning = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
    //...
}
```

A table should have `title` and `description`. Description is always `-fx-font-weight: normal`. Title is  `-fx-font-weight: bold` if `warning`  and `-fx-font-weight: normal` otherwise. Here is a working POJO method.

```
    column.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<Message, String>, TableCell<Message, String>>() {
        public TableCell<Message, String> call(TableColumn<Message, String> param) {
            return new TableCell<Message, String>() {

                @Override
                protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);

                    if (empty || null == getTableRow() || null == getTableRow().getItem()) {
                        setText(null);
                    } else {
                        MyItem m = (MyItem) this.getTableRow().getItem();

                        if (null != m) {
                            setText(m.getTitle());                                
                            String style = m.isWarning()? "-fx-font-weight: bold" : "-fx-font-weight: normal";
                            setStyle(style);
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
        }
    });
```

I would like to move styles to FXML and CSS. Here is what I tried:

```
public class MyController{

    @FXML
    private TableView myTable;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<MyItem, String>  titleColumn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<MyItem, String>  descriptionColumn;

    //...
}
```

```xml
<content>
    <TableView styleClass="fxml-table-style" stylesheets="@my_table_style.css" fx:id="myTable" >
        <columns>
         <TableColumn text="Title">
            <cellValueFactory><PropertyValueFactory property="title" />
            </cellValueFactory>
         </TableColumn>
         <TableColumn text="Body">
            <cellValueFactory><PropertyValueFactory property="description" />
            </cellValueFactory>
         </TableColumn>
        </columns>  
    </TableColumn>
</columns>
```

How to tell Java "use custom-style-1 if column is Title and row `isWarning`; use custom-style-2 otherwise" ?

Comment: You can move the actual style rules (`"-fx-font-weight: bold" : "-fx-font-weight: normal"`) to CSS, but the conditional part will need to remain in Java in your cell factory. You can have the Java code just switch a pseudoclass on and off.

Answer (score 2):

One thing you can do with CSS is write selectors that take into account the parents of a `Node`.

It would be appropriate to add a preudoclass to the `TableRow`s where the warning property is `true`:

```
public class WarningRowFactory implements Callback<TableView<MyItem>, TableRow<MyItem>> {

    private static final PseudoClass WARNING = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("warning");

    @Override
    public TableRow<MyItem> call(TableView<MyItem> table) {
        return new TableRow<MyItem>() {

            private final InvalidationListener listener = observable -> pseudoClassStateChanged(WARNING, getItem() != null && getItem().isWarning());

            @Override
            public void updateItem(MyItem item, boolean empty) {
                if (getItem() != null) {
                    getItem().warningProperty().removeListener(listener);
                }

                super.updateItem(item, empty);

                if (item != null) {
                    item.warningProperty().addListener(listener);
                }

                listener.invalidated(null);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

```xml
<TableView styleClass="fxml-table-style" stylesheets="@my_table_style.css" fx:id="myTable" >
    <rowFactory>
        <WarningRowFactory />
    </rowFactory>
    ...
```

```css
.table-row-cell .table-cell {
    -fx-font-weight: normal;
}

.table-row-cell:warning .table-cell {
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: What should go here: ` <WarningRowFactory />`? IDE highlights it in red: can't resolve.

Comment: You need to add the appropriate import for the class as import in the processing instructions at the beginning of the fxml file.

Comment: Unable to coerce ...WarningRowFactory to javafx.util.Callback<javafx.scene.control.TableView,javafx.scene.control.TableRow

Comment: Have you implemented `javafx.util.Callback`? The code did not yield this error when I tested it...